# Weird "|" on the top of my html page?

Tags: html, css

I am having this issue and I think it might be in my coding. A "|" appears at the top of my screen. I can not find it in my code. And right where that "|" I would like to insert one of my images. Could someone please help and locate where this "|" is?

Thank you so much for whomever is helping me :) I appreciate it!

[Weird "|"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lixos.png)

Actually! This is an update! I have found out what was wrong and why that was appearing! Where  is There is the margin, the border, and the background. Once I got rid of those three and the line went away!

Thank you for whomever tried helping me!

Code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head <p><small>{PEBKAC} &#169; 2017</small></p>

<title>{PEBKAC} - Log In or Sign Up</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<bodystyle="background-color:white;">

<br> <br> <br>

<style>

div1 {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-top: -70px;
 margin-bottom: -30px;
 margin-right: 250px;
 margin-left: 930px;
 background-color: powderblue;
 text-align: center;
}

</style>

<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 

<div1>
<div class="container">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div id="login" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <form>

      <br><br><br><br><br><br>

      E-mail:<br>
      <input type="text" name="e-mail"><br><br>
      Password:<br>
      <input type="password" name="psw"><br><br>

      <button type="button">Log In!</button><br><br>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="signup" class="tab-pane fade">
    <form action="/action_page.php">

      <br><br><br><br><br><br>

      Username:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Username"><br><br>
      E-mail:<br>
      <input type="email" name="e-mail"><br><br>
      Password:<br>
      <input type="password" name="psw"><br><br>
      <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="file:///C:/Users/White-Chocolate/Desktop/TypeTwister/Terms.html">Terms</a> and <a href="file:///C:/Users/White-Chocolate/Desktop/TypeTwister/Privacy%20Policy.html">Privacy Policy</a>. <br> 
<br>
      <button type="button">Sign Up!</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a link to a screenshot that shows the issue.

Comment: I don't see this mysterious "|" symbol when I view your code in a browser. What browser and OS version are you running? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, let me do that right now!

Comment: I will provide a screenshot. I am on win 10 and google chrome

Comment: I have provided the screenshot.

Comment: The markup you're showing here is pretty invalid. You might want to fix that before worrying about odd characters.

Comment: Tieson T. I do not understand what you mean. Could you explain more please?

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket on the head tag, you can't have elements like p or small in the head, and you're missing a space between body and style, just to point out the most obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give css `border: 1px solid black;` to `div1` that raise weird "|" and technically your html code is not proper.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <p><small>{PEBKAC} &#169; 2017</small> </p>
  <title>{PEBKAC} - Log In or Sign Up</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:white;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <style>
    div1 {
      /*border: 1px solid black;*/ this css generated weird "|"
      margin-top: -70px;
      margin-bottom: -30px;
      margin-right: 250px;
      margin-left: 930px;
      background-color: powderblue;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div1>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login">Log In</a> </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#signup">Sign Up</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="login" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <form>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br> E-mail:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="e-mail">
            <br>
            <br> Password:
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="psw">
            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="button">Log In!</button>
            <br>
            <br></form>
        </div>
        <div id="signup" class="tab-pane fade">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br> Username:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="Username">
            <br>
            <br> E-mail:
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="e-mail">
            <br>
            <br> Password:
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="psw">
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="file:///C:/Users/White-Chocolate/Desktop/TypeTwister/Terms.html">Terms</a> and <a href="file:///C:/Users/White-Chocolate/Desktop/TypeTwister/Privacy%20Policy.html">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="button">Sign Up!</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the `<div1>` element.

By the way, that's technically not valid HTML. Change your CSS to `#div1 {`, and that element's HTML to `<div id="div1">`.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Could you explain more?

Comment: <div1> isn't HTML. Use an ID instead: <div id="1"> or <div id="div1">

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `<div1>` element. Remove the `1`.
If you want to give it own CSS styling then use `id` instead.

Comment: I have tried to remove the one and it messed up the way it should look. What code should I use for the id?

Comment: just use <div id="1"> and in the CSS use #1 instead of div